# Why Does VarType() Return vbString for a Variant Variable Containing a Long Integer?

Tags: vba, string, ms-access, types, variant

What the title says.

In Access VBA, I have a function that is intended to return a criteria expression from field name and value parameters.

The idea is that for strings, the criterion will use the Like operator to permit pattern matching, *e.g.*, `Party Like '*f*'` and for long integers, *i.e.*, PK values, the criterion will use the equality operator (=), *e.g.*, `PartyID = 5822`.  Currently, this is conditioned on the variant subtype of the passed value parameter.

The function is below but **the problem** is that VarType() evaluates the **Variant** variable containing a long integer as being of the string subtype.  *I.e.*, VarType() returns 8 (*i.e.*, **vbString**) when evaluating a **Variant** variable containing a long integer, whereas one would expect it to return 3 (*i.e.*, **vbLong**).  Tests indicate that this behavior also exists in the calling code, *i.e.*, VarType() returns 8 (*i.e.*, **vbString**) even for `ctl.Value`.  Recall that the **Value** property data type of all Access controls is **Variant**.

**The question** is why this is occurring, and specifically how to get VarType to behave as documented.

```
Private Function CriterionCreate(ByVal strFieldName As String, varValue As Variant) As String
100     Dim strCriterion As String
    
200     Select Case VarType(varValue)
            Case vbLong     '=3.  For long integer PKs.
202             strCriterion = strFieldName & " = " & varValue
210         Case vbString   '=8.  For strings & text PKs.
211             strCriterion = strFieldName & mLikeThis(varValue)
220         Case vbNull     'Blank / empty record.
221             strCriterion = ""
229     End Select
    
300     CriterionCreate = strCriterion
End Function
```

I will note that the calling code iterates Form.Controls and assigns each control regardless of type to the variable `ctl`, which is declared `As Control`, not as a specific control type.  The Control object does not have a **Value** property, although ctl.Value returns the appropriate value, even though IntelliSense won't autocomplete the property name correctly.  No reason exists to think that this would affect the behavior of VarType() or the character of the data but perhaps the data somehow changes character passing via a property so specified, in which case this is an undocumented bug, besides being fundamentally inconsistent with the notion of **Variant**.

**Edit**:  The calling code is:

`strCriterion = CriterionCreate(strFieldName, ctl.Value)`

Comment: What type has field, that is bound to contorl with that problem?  What type is shown for `varValue` at "locals window" when break at 200 line? How do you exactly call `CriterionCreate` inside loop?

Comment: Since `Variant` accepts anything, it can be loaded with a `String`, a `Double`, an `Object` and so on. `VarType` returns the type of the **loaded** value. Where from your code place values in `varValue` and where from it takes the respective values? Most probably, they are really are strings...

Comment: Option Explicit may help here. Here is how to turn on `Option Explicit` by default for all VBA Code modules  ...  Access > Create > Module > Tools > Options > Editor > Require variable declaration > Tick the box > OK

Comment: Add a Debug.Print Typename(varValue) just before the case statement to check the type.

Comment: You also need to show us the code where the variable passed as varValue is assigned.  If you are taking a value from a form then its likely that the values of the field is returned as a string.

Comment: @4dmonster, the field type is Number, Long Integer.  The type shown is Variant/String.  The calling code is in my edit to the OP.

Comment: @FandDuru, as noted in the OP, "Tests indicate that this behavior also exists in the calling code, i.e., VarType() returns 8 (i.e., vbString) even for ctl.Value."  Also, as noted in my responses to other comments, the ControlSource type is Number, Long Integer.  Simply, the value loaded is a **Long** and not a string but is evaluated as the latter throughout.

Comment: @user10186832, all modules have been configured with Option Explicit by default.

Comment: @freeflow, TypeName there returns `TypeName(varValue) = String`

Comment: @freeflow, not necessarily, but I added the calling code in an edit to the OP.  As you will see, ctl.Value is passed directly as a parameter.  *I.e.*, ctl.Value isn't first assigned to a variable before the variable is passed as a parameter; it's passed directly.  Also, as noted in the OP, VarType(ctl.Value) returns 8, *i.e.*, vbString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Andre, who dropped the breadcrumb that led to a solution, which emerged after a grand tour of the **ComboBox** object and its properties, as follows.

[EDIT:  The following works perfectly well but it turns out the IsNumeric() function will accurately evaluate **Long** data returned by an unbound ComboBox that VarType() incorrectly characterizes as a **String**.]

[TL;DR:  An unbound **ComboBox** fails to return accurately typed data.  So, instead reference **ComboBox.Recordset** to wrangle accurately typed data from an unbound **ComboBox**.]

The breadcrumb is that an unbound Access TextBox returns text (*i.e.*, a string) by default.  The problem I was having was with an unbound ComboBox, but still.

This is entirely unintuitive because the data is a Long Integer and **Value** properties all are **Variant**, which suggests that the data type would be preserved.

Instead, it seems that **ComboBox.Value** evaluates **ControlSource** to determine its data subtype rather than the data itself.  If a combo box ControlSource is a FK field in a table, that field likely is **Long**, so **ComboBox.Value** returns that type.  An unbound combo box has no reference, however, so **ComboBox.Value** defaults to **vbString**, perhaps because that is the type of the **ControlSource** property itself.

- **Note** that this issue is most likely to arise with unbound combo boxes.  The **Text** and **Value** properties of an unbound TextBox will be blank.  An unbound ComboBox, however, will have these properties populated by its **RowSource** property.
- Thus, while **ComboBox.Value** appears to evaluate **ControlSource** to establish its subtype, it does not appear to evaluate **RowSource** in a similar manner.

Nowhere, besides here, is this documented.

So, an unbound **ComboBox**' **Value** property fails to return accurately typed data.  Other data references are available, however, albeit with subtle distinctions:

- **ComboBox.Value**, again, is typed **vbString**.
- **ComboBox.Column(0)** also is typed **vbString**.  This seems odd because **ComboBox.Column** presumably would reference the data directly and if so, ought to be able to correctly type it.  Other behavior of the **Form** object suggests that objects interact internally with JET SQL dynasets, not their RecordSource, ControlSource, or Recordset objects directly.  If so, then perhaps Access types all such data as **vbString**.  Stay tuned on this topic.
- **ComboBox.Recordset.Fields(0)** is typed **vbLong**, which is a bit of a breakthrough.  Sadly, references to **ComboBox.Recordset** return all records.  **The solution**, then, is to filter the recordset.

It may seem like a bit of work but the code I came up with to wrangle accurately typed data from an unbound **ComboBox** object follows.  **Its advantage** is that it does not require further inspection or any use of a type conversion function to coerce type.

```
230                 If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
231                     Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
232                     Dim rstFiltered As DAO.Recordset

240                     Set rst = ctl.Recordset

250                     With rst
251                         .Filter = .Fields(0).Name & " = " & ctl.Value
252                         Set rstFiltered = .OpenRecordset
259                     End With

260                     varValue = rstFiltered.Fields(0)

267                     Set rstFiltered = Nothing
268                     Set rst = Nothing
269                 End If

270                 strCriterion = CriterionCreate(strFieldName, varValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. As noted in the comments, `VarType` doesn't evaluate the value of the variable, but what type of value was "loaded" into it.

Unbound Access textboxes return text by default. You can force them to be numeric with the Format property, but this will always be a Double number. I don't see a way to force a textbox to return a Long Int value with properties alone.

On a test form, I have 3 text boxes:

1. bound to a Long Int column
2. unbound, no format
3. unbound, format "0"

This code:

```
Private Sub cmdRun_Click()

    Dim ctl As Access.control
    Dim varValue As Variant
    
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
            varValue = ctl.Value
            Debug.Print ctl.Name, varValue, VarType(varValue)
        End If
    Next ctl
    
End Sub
```

returns this, after entering "1" and "2" into the unbound boxes (ID is always 0):

```
ID                          0             3  (vbLong)
Unbound_NoFormat            1             8  (vbString)
Unbound_FormatNumber        2             5  (vbDouble)
```

To force 3. to vbLong, you need VBA:

```
Private Sub Unbound_FormatNumber_AfterUpdate()

    With Me.Unbound_Formatnumber
        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            .Value = CLng(.Value)
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

then its value has VarType = vbLong.

This is IMHO more effort than specifying the types in code.
In forms where I do "filter by search textboxes", I do:

```
Call AddCriteria(Me, S, "Projekt_Nr", dbLong)
Call AddCriteria(Me, S, "Projekt_Name", dbText)
Call AddCriteria(Me, S, "SomeDate", dbDate)
```

with AddCriteria being a wrapper function for [Application.BuildCriteria](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.buildcriteria), which allows filtering with expressions (">=100", "3 or 5").

Comment: you put your finger on the issue, which is that an unbound control returns a string by default.  This isn't terribly intuitive because **Value** properties are **Variant** but suggests that **Value** derives its subtype from **ControlSource**, not the data itself or **RowSource**.

Comment: the CLng approach also is clearly the means to coerce type.  Still, it and your elegant AddCriteria() leave the question of discerning type in the first place.